# BigQuery Load CSV/TSV that contains escaped tab

Tags: csv, parsing, google-bigquery, escaping

EDITED: Providing more sample data and also the schema used

I am having issues loading tab delimited (`*.tsv`) files into BigQuery via CLI.

Two rows of sample data (`test.tsv`) below. Link to sample data [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1At24Nujza8A7oxF-T2KPYRtIdtrjrs6V/view?usp=sharing)

```
user    2019-04-30 11:12:42 3459323 6461614 945923  683716374614    14362   30475264    9919323 15502   144353  14115   57  1.11.11.11      0   1   23  75  aerfla/8.0 (aerf; aerf aerf aa 22_2 like str aef X) aerfae/65.91.15 (aea like fae) aerf/a1548 (556544)  xxxx    x   xxx 77023   992015  file:///path/path   Product     file:///path/path   Product Detail      file:///path/path   3   file:///path/path   3       Product Detail                          xx:Pe Matten - Kids'                227,288,289,101,114,135,147,153
user    2019-04-30 11:12:31 89459323    41661614    8056994 5481614 54351   60815513    59169523273 96602   44350   1556644115  57  1.11.11.11      0   1   67  35  adf/6.1 (aerfae; ae aerf 1S 12_3 like eec ee x) aerfapaerfb/615.0.5 (aerfL, like aao) aerfe/1E18 (6544) xxxxxxld    xxx xxx 770 84015   file:///path/path/  LLL: aerfa      file:///path/path/path/path/            file:///path/path/path/ 3   file:///path/path   3       Search Results                                              
user    2019-04-30 11:12:32 071459323   753717461   805659323   7461614 4452    68296384    76953768    6602    1351    1556644115  57  1.11.11.11      0   1   76  5   aerfa/9.0 (aerfae; xxx aerfa xx 19_0 like xaerf xx X) aerfaerf/605.1.15 (aerfaerf, like aerfaerf) aerfaerf/1aerf5E148 (52995544)    xxxxxx  xx  xxxx    770 84015   file:///path/path/  Product     file:///path/path   Product Detail      file:///path/path/  3   file:///path/path/  3       PPP Detail                          DDD:AAA Glove\  - Kids'             227,288,289,211,114,135,147,153
```

The `test_schema.json` file:

```
[
    {"name":"col0", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col1", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col2", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col3", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col4", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col5", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col6", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col7", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col8", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col9", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col10", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col11", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col12", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col13", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col14", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col15", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col16", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col17", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col18", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col19", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col20", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col21", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col22", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col23", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col24", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col25", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col26", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col27", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col28", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col29", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col30", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col31", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col32", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col33", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col34", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col35", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col36", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col37", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col38", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col39", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col40", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col41", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col42", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col43", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col44", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col45", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col46", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col47", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col48", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    {"name":"col49", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
]
```

The BQ CLI command that works without any errors is:

```
bq load \
--field_delimiter=tab \
--source_format=CSV \
--allow_jagged_rows \
--replace \
mydataset.test \
test.tsv \
test_schema.json
```

The command will **not** work without the `--allow_jagged_rows` option. Using `max_bad_records=100` or `--ignore_unknown_values` did not help either. The error I receive if I do not use `--allow_jagged_rows`:

```
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references
column position 49, but line starting at position:0 contains only
49 columns.
```

When using `--allow_jagged_rows` to upload the data into BQ, there's an issue with parsing the value at `col43`. A screenshot of latter half of BQ table after loading using the CLI:
[image]

For the sample data provided, the issues occur at column `col43`. The first row and third row have been parsed correctly. The second row shows that BQ splits the value of `DDD:AAA Glove\  - Kids'` into two and populates both `col43` and `col44` instead of just `col43`. Furthermore, it affects the population of the columns after it. It is clear that the BQ parser is not acknowledging that the `tab` character is preceded by `\` in `DDD:AAA Glove\    - Kids'`.

Is there a way to escape a `tab` that is preceded by `\`? Most of the examples I've seen regarding escape characters when loading `CSV` into BQ has to do with escaping quotes. I haven't found anything helpful for my problem yet. I am also trying to avoid modifying these files with a find/replace.

If unable to escape this `\\t`, I'm wondering if my only hope may be to read in each row as a single string into a BQ staging table, then do final parsing in BQ with SQL where I might have more control.

Comment: Could you please specify your exact table structure? You can separate columns with "l". It's quite unclear at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: @muscat updated. Hopefully more clear now

Comment: I recreated your table and the problem is not in backslash character. It worked for me without deviding the table for more columns. Have you checked the logs for more specific error? If you need to insert rows that successfully match the schema and want to ignore failed rows then use the `--max_bad_records` option. The default value is 0. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @muscat I put up some more info in the OP. I was not able to have any success using `--max_bad_records` and I also do not want to ignore those rows. Can you see if you're still successful with new sample data provided?

Comment: Could you please provide ready to download tsv/csv file with the sample data? I can't parse it correctly.

Comment: Added a Google Drive LInk to test file

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it again, and noticed that in the `test.tsv` file, following part: `DDD:AAA Glove\  - Kids'` is already separated. "DDD:AAA Glove\" part is placed in col43 and "- Kids'" in col44. So it works correct. I've changed manually col43 by adding the part from col44, than delete `- Kids'` in col44, and I got the result you expected: `DDD:AAA Glove\ - Kids'` in col 43. Moreover the population of the columns after it is correct now.

Comment: Right, but in a sense it's not working correct because that separation is supposed to be escaped by the "\".  What you've done to make it work is a very manual and specific process and I'm wondering if there are options in `bq load` command that can prevent me from doing this.

Comment: I read trough the bq load documentation and I can't see any appropriate option. The problem is with your initial dataset so you need to write SQL queries to perform all the cleanups or for example use data wrangling in Google Data Fusion.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question, unfortunately. I'm trying to find a one line solution using `bq load`. Your method is one of many alternative solutions to deal with this issue.

Comment: Okay, as I said before there is no appropriate option in the the bq load documentation for now.